# standard non-alphanumeric sort order

Tags: sorting, character, non-alphanumeric

Is there a standardised sort order for NON-alpha-numeric characters that is used across most systems / programs?  For instance, when I create a bunch of items with symbols as the first character and then sort by `Name` in Windows 10, I get this order:

[image]

But are there any standards on this?  The order of 0-9 and A-Z is obvious of course, so I was wondering if there's a normal order for anything non-alphanumeric in computing.